# Transaction too large when opening PDF-s, XLS, DOC

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, kotlin, document

Part of my app is to show documents that device receives from server as bytearray. I approached this problem by using Intent.ACTION_VIEW but it shows an error saying Transaction too large as the files are some 9 MB.

I read about this error and is pretty much self-explanatory. Is there a way to save this bytearray as a local file and pass only the path to the desired application? In what way can I approach this problem?

Also, can I use the Apache library to render these files in app?

Code:

```
        if(response.isSuccessful){
                var name = name1
                val fileBytes = response.body()?.bytes()
                if (fileBytes == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.no_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    return
                }
                if (name.isEmpty() || name == "") name = "testFile"


                val mFolder = File(context.filesDir, "/androidapp")
                val mFile = File(mFolder.absolutePath, "$name.${mimeType.split("/")[1]}")

                if(!mFolder.exists()){
                    mFolder.mkdir()
                }

                if (!mFile.exists()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "showPrintPreview: File does not exists")
                    try {
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "showPrintPreview: File created" + mFile.createNewFile()
                        )
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "showPrintPreview: " + mFile.isDirectory
                        )
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
                try {
                    val fos = FileOutputStream(mFile)
                    fos.write(fileBytes)
                    fos.flush()
                    fos.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Log.d("showPrintPreview: ", e.message)
                    // handle exception
                }
                try {
                    val uri: Uri = getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName,
                        mFile
                    )
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType)
                    //            
                   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    //            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent)
                } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    showNoPrintAppDialog(context, mimeType.split("/")[1])
                }
            }`
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 996448 bytes
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 996448 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1145)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3891)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
```

Comment: "I approached this problem by using Intent.ACTION_VIEW but it shows an error saying Transaction too large as the files are some 9 MB" -- you do not pass the PDF in the `Intent`. You pass a `Uri` pointing to the PDF in the `Intent`. "Is there a way to save this bytearray as a local file and pass only the path to the desired application?" -- save the `byte[]` to a file in `getCacheDir()` (method available on `Context` subclasses), then use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` that you can hand to other apps via `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: EDIT: I added the code. I am passing the Uri, it throws the error. What do I do?

Comment: You are calling `setDataAndType()` twice. The first time, you are providing a `Uri` from `FileProvider`. The second time, you are passing `Uri.fromFile(file)`. It is unclear what `file` is. Regardless, whatever it is, it is too big, and the second `setDataAndType()` call wipes out the first one. Try removing the second `setDataAndType()` call.

Comment: I think android is trying to save in bundle data that comes from server, that is too big. How do I handle that?

Comment: I cannot answer that, as I do not know where in your app you are holding the data that comes from your server. But you may be right -- the `TransactionTooLargeException` could be coming from the saved instance state `Bundle` and not from the `Intent`.

Comment: I save my data in LiveData inside ViewModels. What should I do to ensure that data is cleared when I leave fragment and reload when I come back. I am trying to set value to null with a helper function inside the viewmodel.

Comment: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] for this new concern. In general, your `ViewModel` will be cleared when the fragment is destroyed.